# Write MySQL query to get the time user spent in each book page from the following table

Tags: jquery, mysql, database

I have a table that shows the times when user change pages from prev to the next. I need to get a table that shows how much time user spent in each page.

for example

```
page | time 
1    | 10s
2    | 20s
```

[image: table with time stampts when user goes from one page to next page]

Here is what I did but there should be a better way without using while

set @page_number = 1;

while @page_number < select max(next_page) from all_page_stats

select 
@page_number as page_number,

sum((case when prev_page = @page_number then TIME_TO_SEC(event_time) else -(TIME_TO_SEC(event_time)) end)) as time

from all_page_stats where next_page = @page_number or prev_page = @page_number;

set @page_number = @page_number +1;

end while;

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: What is the type of column- `event_time` ?  Is it possible to have more than one entry for same `prev_page` and `next_page` ? I mean `prev_page`=0 and `next_page`=1, will this combination be repeated again somewhere in the table ?

Comment: why your `prev_page`, and `next_page` has non arranged values, in row 11 `next_page` is lower than `prev_page`

Comment: Prev_page is redundant. However, in the event that a user flicks forward several pages in the space of a single second, your model will fail. You need either to store fractions of a second or a separate incrementing PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: @mobasherfasihy e-books are amazing. They let you scroll backwards as well as forwards

Comment: the reason that pages are repeated is because the user went back and previewed the first pages.

Comment: in those situation it must be assumed that the user spent zero time on those pages when we got same time stampt for both rows

Comment: Also, the final two rows don't make sense.

Comment: That assumption is fine. But still, we need a PRIMARY KEY - a way of uniquely identifying rows.

Comment: @Strawberry, user went 8 to7 then he went from 7 to 6 and 6 to 5 very fast (less than a second) therefore both 7 to 6 and 6 to 5 have the same event time. 6 to 5 shown on top of 7 to 6 which is cropped from the image

Comment: See. That demonstrates the importance of a PK (and the redundancy of prev_page)

Comment: Have you checked my answer? is it ok or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this: what you need to add is an auto increment id in your table

```
SELECT a.prev_page, a.next_page, a.event_time, 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,a.event_time,b.event_time) AS time 
FROM ebook a INNER JOIN ebook b ON b.id = (a.id + 1) 
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bd010/1) link

output is like:[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it will not work since you assumed we can pair every row with its next row and it is not always true for example the user turn from 8 to 7 he swipe pages very fast from  7 to 6 and 6 to 5 in less than a second. Since the data’s primary key is uuid and its not sorted 6 to 5 appears first. So we are having page turns as follows 8 to 7 , 5 to 6 followed by 6 to 7. As you can see in this example you should not have paired it with the next row.

Comment: if we could sort the data so the difference between "next_page" columns would have been 1 then we could have applied your solution

Comment: @user3505838 I have not paired two rows by `prev_page` and `next_page` values, instead i have used from `id` of table, and its not important that two row is sequential or no.